# How to connect to Magento after I've changed the password for database?

Tags: mysql, magento

I cannot connect to Magento after I put a password for my user on MySQL Database. How can I fix this?

```
Error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'xxx'@'localhost' (using password: YES).
```

I tried to remove the pasword but without success by going to phpMyAdmin and running this command on my database in SQL

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'xxx_username'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('');
```

and I got this error:

```
#1044 - Access denied for user 'xxx'@'localhost' to database 'mysql'
```

How can I update this password on Magento? Or remove it from database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a two step process.  First, you configure your Magento database credentials in the following file/location

```
<!-- File: app/etc/local.xml -->
<connection>
    <host><![CDATA[server_name]]></host>
    <username><![CDATA[username]]></username>
    <password><![CDATA[password]]></password>
    <dbname><![CDATA[schema_name]]></dbname>
    <active>1</active>
</connection>
```

Step two is clearing your Magento cache.  Magento caches its configuration files so it doesn't need to load them from disk on each request.  In a standard setup, you can clear your cache by removing any files/folders in the following directory

```
var/cache/...
```

However, if your system has had additional scaling work performed on it, it may be necessary to flush other cache systems manually.

Comment: removing the folders from cache after modifying local.xml was the trick.. wonder why no one mentioned in any of the other answers